# How to assign json string contents and keep formatting?

Tags: java, json

I have a block of json that I want to initialize a string with and I want to keep the formatting but this doesn't work.

The json will be much larger than this but just looking for possibilities for assigment w/formatting?

```
private static final String whateverXXX ='{
    "phonetype":"N95",
        "cat":"WP"
}';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible. You cannot put pretty-print JSON in a Java source file, ie. a `.java` file.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5), among other things, states the following about `String` literals

> It is a compile-time error for a line terminator to appear after the
>   opening " and before the closing matching ".

Consider putting it in a separate text file and reading it in your Java code.